# Determine if one string is a permutation of another using a hashmap (optimal solution)

Tags: java, hashmap

The problem is given two strings, write a method to decide if one is a permutation of the other. I came up with a code that works fine however I'd like to know if there is another solution that doesn't require a repetitive use of a for-loop in my hash function. Is it possible? Is it optimally better to have one for-loop versus two or does it not matter?

Main method would have the following call:

```
hashFunction("dog", "god");
```

which returns true. Is there a better solution that would call isPermutation instead?

Here is my code:

```
public static void isPermutation (Map<Character, Integer> charMap){
    boolean isPerm = true;
    for(Integer value : charMap.values()){
        if(value != 2)
            isPerm = false;
    }
    System.out.println(isPerm);
}

public static void hashFunction(String msg1, String msg2){

    Map<Character, Integer> hMap = new HashMap <Character, Integer>();

    for(Character c : msg1.toCharArray()){
        if(!hMap.containsKey(c)){
            hMap.put(c, 1);
        }else{
            hMap.put(c, hMap.get(c)+1);
        }
    }

    for(Character c : msg2.toCharArray()){
        if(!hMap.containsKey(c)){
            hMap.put(c, 1);
        }else{
            hMap.put(c, hMap.get(c)+1);
        }
    }

    isPermutation(hMap);
}
```

I feel like having two for-loops doing the exact same thing is redundant and unnecessary. However, I'm not sure how to do it in another way. Please help!

Comment: Take a look at this page: https://leetcode.com/problems/permutation-in-string/solution/ They discuss many possible solutions to the problem.

Comment: Your code won't work if a string has more than one of the same letter.

Comment: The two loops shouldn't be doing the same thing.  One should be counting; the other should be uncounting. (And of course, at the end, you'd thus look for every value to be 0, not 2.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if the strings aren't the same length, then they aren't permutations.  Check the lengths first.  (You may also want to null-check your parameters.)

```
if (msg1.length() != msg2.length()) return false;
```

Next, you aren't taking into account if the messages themselves contain duplicate characters.  What about "message" and "message"?  You'll get a count of `4`, not `2`.

Instead of adding, *subtract* `1` from each character you find in `msg2` in the map.  If you go below `0`, you've found more instances of a character in `msg2` than in `msg1` and you can immediately return `false`.  If a character isn't even found in the map, then you've found a character in `msg2` that doesn't exist in `msg`, and you can immediately return `false`.

```
for(Character c : msg2.toCharArray()){
    if(!hMap.containsKey(c)){
        return false;
    }else{
        int freq = hMap.get(c) - 1;
        if (freq < 0)
            return false;
        hMap.put(c, freq - 1);
    }
}
```

If you get through the entire string `msg2`, then you know that no counts of characters in `msg2` are higher than in `msg1` and the total number of characters is the same, so you can return `true` and you don't even need the `isPermutation` method from your code.

If you have a limited set of possible characters, e.g. ASCII-only, then you can replace the `Map` with an `int[]` for performance.  The array's size would be the range of characters that are allowed, the index would be the ASCII code for the character, and the array elements would be the frequencies.